# MySQL where clause strangely returns all rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Someone tried SQL injection on my website. He/she didn't succeed, but something he/she tried caught my attention.

This where clause returns all rows and I have no idea why it does.

`SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn=''=''`

I tried this statement in MySQL and MariaDB, and they both returned all rows. Shouldn't this statement throw a syntax error? Why does it return all rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine this query:

```
select * from MyTable where false='';
```

Then, just divide yours in:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (MyColumn='')=''
```